# Update bower dependencies, bower.json in Ember-CLI app

Tags: bower, ember-cli

Is there a way to update ALL bower dependency versions AND make bower.json reflect those changes?

This would be something similar to doing

```
npm-check-updates -u
```

for npm modules, using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).

Again, I want to update ALL dependencies to their latest available versions, AND reflect those changes in my *bower.json* file. Unless I'm mistaken, the solutions provided elsewhere either update one component at a time, or run *bower update*, which does not seem to update *bower.json*. In fact, it seems to just update the versions to whatever *bower.json* allows.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the linked page has a solution for updating all, but not updating bower.json at the same time.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-update) package help?

Comment: It looks like something I was looking for (assuming it updates bower.json), but I just tried it, and it's way too buggy.

Comment: Also, it's not the first time my question gets voted by people to be closed, or even downvoted, even though I repeat multiple times that it's not exactly like other questions. I wish people would read it carefully before downvoting, etc.

Comment: Note the "possible" in "possible duplicate"